# The largest $\sigma$-algebra generated by a subset

Tags: measure-theory

It is always possible to find a smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains any subset $A$ of a given set $X$ (it is, by definition, the intersection of all the $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ that contain $A$). Now, is the notion of the *largest* $\sigma$-algebra meaningful and possible as well?

One may argue that the largest such $\sigma$-algebra is the union of all $\sigma$-algebras that contain $A$. But the (natural) next question is that, ``is the union of a collection of $\sigma$-algebras a $\sigma$-algebra?''

Comment: $\wp(X)$? $\qquad$

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott Great. I am thinking about the next question.

Comment: The union of a collection of $\sigma$-algebras is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra. Consider two independent Bernoullis (coinflips) $X_1$ and $X_2$; $\sigma(X_1) = \{ \emptyset, \Omega,\{(0,0),(0,1)\},\{(1,0),(1,1)\}\}$ (I hope the notation is obvious: $(X_1, X_2) = (\cdot,\cdot)$). $\sigma(X_2)$ also contains no singletons $\{(\cdot,\cdot)\}$, so neither does $\sigma(X_1) \cup \sigma(X_2)$, but $\sigma(\sigma(X_1)\cup\sigma(X_2))$ does.

Answer (score 1):

The largest $\sigma$-algebra always exists but it is meaningless. It is the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of $X$.

Comment: Ok, but what about a largest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$ such that it is not $\mathcal{P}(X)$, if there is one.