# Is $\sigma(S^c) = \mathcal{P}(X)$, where $S^c$ is a complement of an arbitrary sigma algebra on X?

Tags: measure-theory

Is the smallest sigma-algebra containing the complement of an arbitrary sigma algebra $S$ on $X$ always equal to the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$? In short, does $\sigma(S^c) = \mathcal{P}(X)$?

By complement of a sigma algebra I mean $\mathcal{P}(X) \setminus S$.

EDIT: except the trivial case when $S = \mathcal{P}(X)$

(Definitely, for a non-trivial sigma-algebra, meaning $|S| > 2, S \ne \mathcal{P}(X)$, we *can't* say the opposite, that is "never equal to the power set". Counterexample, when $\sigma(S^c)$ is actually the power set -> $S = \{\{\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{1\}, \{2, 3\}\},X = \{1,2,3\}$.)

Or we can't say anything at all about such $\sigma(S^c)$?

Comment: What if $S=\mathcal{P}(X)$?

Comment: @d.k.o.yes, sorry I forgot to specify, that wouldn’t count

Comment: this is also related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121364/the-largest-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-subset

Answer (score 1):

What about

$$S = \{A \subset \mathbb{R} | A \textit{ countable or } A^c \textit{ countable}\}$$

Then $$S^c = \{A \subset \mathbb{R} | A \textit{ uncountable and } A^c \textit{ uncountable}\}$$

How would $$ \sigma(S^c)$$ include any infite, countable sets?

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, or I mean I thought about that, too :D.

The problem is, when you take e.g. the complement of $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$, you get $0$. That way, you can get any number and so you can get any infinite countable set. Therefore $\sigma(S^c)$ would be the power set.

Maybe some modification would work though.

Comment: Actually, I think it can be easily proven that for an uncountable $X$, the statement in my question holds for every subset or superset of $S$, as you defined it. I might write the proof in an answer, sometime soon.
So when searching for counterexamples, we should avoid subsets and supersets of $S$.

Comment: Therefore in such counterexample $\tilde{S}$, we need to have some $A$, where both $A$ and $A^c$ are uncountable.

Comment: You’re rignt there, my answer wasn’t correct. What about S equals borel sigma algebra? I’m not sure how the sigma generated by non borel measurablesets looks like, and if it’s really the power set.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how it looks like either. I think I'm closer to actually proving the statement. So probably the power set :)

Comment: Yes, I think I proved it. I will post it in a couple of hours

Comment: So I posted the 'proof'. Turns out there is a problem, so it is not really a proof in whole. I described the problem there. Either we can prove the problem statement or we can try to use it to find counterexamples. I think I showed we cannot make $\sigma(S^c)$ smaller by removing from it a countable set (then S would become the power set). However, the problem statement is that maybe we could remove at least one _uncountable_ set and make $\sigma(S^c)$ smaller, while S not becoming the power set.

Comment: Can I ask where you posted the proof?

Comment: But of course, this would be only one class of counterexamples; those where we begin with such defined $S$ – containing all countable sets.

Comment: if you refresh the window, it should be visible as another answer.

Comment: I found a counterexample. Please verify it in the answer (if it’s correct).

Answer (score 1):

Part (ii) of *Lemma*, is unproven.

However, if the *Lemma* holds, I think the rest of the theorem proof holds.

**Theorem in question**

Let $S$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on an arbitrary set $X$, s.t. $S \ne \mathcal{P}(X)$. Then $\sigma(S^c) = \mathcal{P}(X)$.

---

First, inspired by why the situation in the first answer doesn't work, we'll show, that:

**Lemma**

(i) A  $\sigma$-algebra on an arbitrary set $X$ $$S = \{A \subseteq X | A \textit{ countable or } A^c \textit{ countable}\}$$
or (ii) any $\sigma$-algebra generated by superset of $S$, meets the theorem in the question.

*Proof*

If $X$ is countable, then the theorem's premise $\sigma(S) \ne \mathcal{P}(X)$ doesn't hold, resp. the theorem holds. Now for $X$ uncountable:

Take $S$. $S^c$ is non-empty. For any $x \in X$, take a set $A \in S^c$. Then $x \in A \text{ or } x \in A^c$. WLOG, let $x \in A$. $A \setminus \{x\}$ is also uncountable therefore in $S^c$. $(A\setminus\{x\} \cup A^c)^c = \{x\} \in \sigma(S^c)$. Because $\sigma(S^c)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, there are all countable unions of any such one-element sets, therefore there are all countable sets. So $\sigma(S^c) = \mathcal{P}(X)$. So *Lemma* holds for $S$ (i).

[I did not prove (ii). An idea was that we would need to exclude from $\sigma(S^c)$ at least some sets, therefore adding it to $S$, but this would lead to $S$ becoming $\mathcal{P}(X)$.]

A simple observation is also that for any *subset* of $S$ the *Lemma* holds too. (Because if $R \subset S$, $\sigma(R^c) \supseteq \sigma(S^c) = \mathcal{P}(X)$.)

**Proof of the theorem in question**

If $S$ contains all countable sets, then the theorem holds according to the *Lemma*.

If $S$ contains none of the countable sets, then $S^c$ contains all of them, therefore also $\sigma(S^c)$, and plugging it in the *Lemma*, we get contradiction $S = \mathcal{P}(X)$

Now it suffices to show the theorem holds if $S$ contains at least one countable set *and* $S^c$ contains at least one countable set, say set $B$. Note it also means $B^c \in S^c$, because if it weren't $B$ was also in $S$, which is a contradiction.

We will show that whenever $S$ contains *a* one-element set $I=\{i\}$, $\sigma({S^c})$ also contains it, therefore when applying the Lemma for $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma({S^c})$, we get contradiction that $S = \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Focus on the (arbitrary) one-element set $I \in S$. Necessarily, there is set $B^{any} \in \{B, B^c\}, i \in B^{any}$. Set $B^{any} \setminus I$ is either in $S^c$ and we're done, as $I = ((B^{any})^c \cup (B^{any} \setminus I))^c \in \sigma(S^c)$, or it has to be in $S$. But then we get a contradiction -> $B^{any} = B^{any} \setminus I \cup I$  has to be in $S$ *and* it was in $S^c$

We have shown every one-element set is in $S^c$, therefore every countable set is in $\sigma({S^c})$. After applying the *Lemma* for $\sigma({S^c})$,  we get contradiction that $S = \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

After all, I think I have a simple counterexample.

Take $$S = \sigma(\{ A \subset \left[ 0,1\right] | A \textit{ countable }\}  \cup \{A \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \left[ 0,1 \right] \} )$$
Then both $S$ and $\sigma(S^c)$ are not $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, right?

Comment: For example, I don’t expect set [0,1/2] to be in S. 
Or set [2,3] to be in $\sigma(S^c)$

Comment: Hmm, this might be wrong. There actually is [2,3] in $\sigma(S^c)$, as there is also [0,1] and necessarily $[0,1/2] \cup [2,3]$